# Is there a way to slice out multiple 2D numpy arrays from one 2D numpy array in one batch operation?

Tags: numpy, numpy-slicing, numpy-indexing

I have a numpy array `heatmap` of shape `(img_height, img_width)` and another array `bboxes` of shape `(K, 4)`, where `K` is a number of bounding boxes.
Each bounding box is defined
like so: `[x_top_left, y_top_left, width, height]`.
Here's an example of such array:

```
bboxes = np.array([
    [0, 0, 4, 7],
    [3, 4, 3, 4],
    [7, 2, 3, 7]
])
```

`heatmap` is initally filled with zeros.
What I need to do is to put value 1 for each bounding box in it's corresponding place.
The resulting `heatmap` should be:

```
heatmap = np.array([
    [1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0],
    [1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0],
    [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0],
    [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0],
    [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
])
```

**Important** things to note:

- axis 0 corresponds to image height
- axis 1 corresponds to image width

I've already solved this using python for loop, like so:

```
for bbox in bboxes:
    #       y_top_left:y_top_left + img_height, x_top_left:x_top_left + img_width
    heatmap[bbox[1] : bbox[1] + bbox[3], bbox[0] : bbox[0] + bbox[2]] = 1
```

I would like to avoid using python for loops (if it's possible) and be able to do something like this:

```
heatmap[bboxes[:,1] : bboxes[:,1] + bboxes[:,3], bboxes[:,0]:bboxes[:,0] + bboxes[:,2]] = 1
```

Is there a way of doing such multiple slicing in numpy?

I am aware of [numpy integer array indexing](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html#integer-array-indexing), but to generate such indices I am also unable to avoid python for loops.

Comment: No, slices need to be contiguous or monotonously spaced, and this output doesn't allow either.  An iterative method is probably your best bet.